# How to refresh page with php after a data of the user is changed in database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm trying to make a page to verify users and once they get verified it should automatically display the new content.

I've already tried with:

```php
<?php if ($user[ 'verified']) echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL='.$location.'">'; ?>
```

But the issue with this is that if the user is verified the site keeps constantly refreshing.

```html
<div class="notverified" <?php if ($user[ 'verified']) echo 'style="display:contents;"'; ?>>
   <span>You are verified (example)</span>
</div>
```

I expect that automatically appears the new content once the user is verified in db OR that once the user is verified, the site reloads but only one time.

Comment: I'd suggest you go with a javascript-ajax implementation to achieve this. Make a JS function to periodically poll the state of the database and once new update is received, refresh/update the page from the JS code. The role of PHP code would be to respond to the ajax (HTTP request) call from the JS function with proper data from the database.

Comment: @FaisalRahmanAvash Hmm, any other solution besides ajax? We rather not coding our site with ajax.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is the use of web sockets/server push. You can checkout socket.io. Although if you are trying to steer clear of JS altogether, you pretty much have no other option than using HTML meta refresh as current web tech works in a Client-Server Model.

Comment: @FaisalRahmanAvash Yea we use JavaScript.

Comment: you can probably check this library out if you intend to use [web sockets with PHP using Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)

Comment: I solved it with JavaScript by doing `document.location.reload(true)`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you refresh the page, instead of using ajax to get content.

```
<?php if ($user[ 'verified']) echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL='.$location.'">'; ?>
```

when the user verified == true, the browser refresh, and the next time the user verified == true again, and of course, the site keeps constantly refreshing.

so, if the $user verified, you should trigger the ajax for getting new content.

Comment: Any other solution besides ajax? We rather not coding our site with ajax.

Comment: or you can create a button, and if the user verified, they can click to it, trigger refresh the site.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this with JavaScript by just adding `document.location.reload(true)`

```
$('.verify-account').click(function() {
    $(this).prepend('<i style="margin-top:5px;margin-left:5px" class="fa fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> ');
    $.post('verify', function(data) {
        if (data.status == 'success') {
            $('.accountver').html('<strong class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Verified</strong>');
            $('.verify-account').html('<p1>Verified</p1>');
            $('.verify-account').prop('disabled', true);
            $('.verification').empty();
            document.location.reload(true)
        }
        $('.verify-account').find('i').remove();
        showAlert(data.status, data.message);
    }).fail(function(response) {
        $('.verify-account').find('i').remove();
        showAlert('error', 'There was a problem while perform this action. '+ response.responseText);
    });
});
```